# How to make two legends on a single data in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

Suppose I have a table which is containing data for 2 years like for 2021 and 2022 and I want to show data in line chart with 2021 data into solid line and for 2022 in dotted in a single chart

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the `SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR` DAX function.

Using it, you could create two measures such as

```
TotalSales = SUM(Sales[SalesAmount])

PreviousYearTotalSales = CALCULATE(
  SUM(Sales[SalesAmount]), 
  SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(Date[Date]))
```

and plot those out on your linechart